# How to align a sqllite3 database output in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, formatting

I know how to align the fetched values using tabulate or other techniques on console 
but the problem arises on GUI when using tkinter. I used aligning methods also but still I can't get it just like I want it to be [image: screenshot]

Above is the output I am getting but I need this to be more neat and professional.

Below is the printing code.
[image: code]

Apologies for commenting some lines of code and tabulate method line

I created grid and label for every column and implemented by same logic but still 
debit column's ""|"" isn't coming to format

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Use `justify = RIGHT` attribute inside `Label` widget.This will justify your data to right direction.

Comment: it worked only on credit column but not on other three column they have become more od

Comment: Are all the columns are contains grid layout ???If not, change every column label layout type to grid.

Comment: there is only one label and grid which is containing the text as shown in code

Comment: can you please explain me the implementation of your 3rd comment in my code

Comment: Is your output code in tabular form or not ??

Comment: I have used tabulate method but since then it didn't work on tkinter nicely I moved to looping through my data

Comment: please see my edited post

Comment: okay guys thank you I have done it